# How to fix Safari print preview crash after upgrade to Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, safari, printing

After upgrading to Mountain Lion, opening the print dialog in Safari.

Printing was fine before the upgrade. Also printing still works in my VMs under Parallels.

How to fix Safari print preview crash after upgrading to Mountain Lion?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details? How does it crash, are there any error messages, does printing from Pages/Word/Mail still work, is anything written to the log files (use Console.app) at the time of the crash?

Answer (score 1):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4213152?start=0&tstart=0

It's an issue with the most recent driver version. Open Finder, select Go > Go to Folder and write:

/Library/Printers/hp/PDEs

and delete:

hpPostScriptPDE.plugin